# Better way to find nonzero indices and values in a 2D array

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython, simd

I am still fighting against the problem of finding the `i`, `j` indices (and the corresponding values) of nonzero entries in a **dense**, **single precision**, **Fortran-ordered** 2D array. I am using Cython via Python with some C in the middle.

I apologize in advance as this post is going to be horribly long.

### Introduction

I have to process thousands (sometimes millions) of medium-size 2D arrays (sometimes 700 x 1,000, sometimes 6,000 x 7,000 and so on), which are quite sparse but they are provided as dense (density can be as low as 0.02% and as high as 1-2%). These matrices sometimes have some sort of structure but in general this is not predictable.

I have tried numpy.nonzero and the Scipy sparse stuff, but they are unfortunately slower than what I have.

I am asking this question to see **if there are possibilities for improvements in performance** in my (possibly incorrect) code - i.e., make it faster - but also to learn new things from more experienced people.

My proficiency in Cython is very limited. My knowledge of C is abysmal (really, pretty much zero). Everything I know about SIMD instructions can be written on a postage stamp in large letters.

I have scoured StackOverflow back and forth and found answers to kind-of-similar questions, many of them with very advanced SIMD solutions. But since I know nothing about SIMD, I am unable to modify them to suit my needs.

### Configuration

- Windows 10 64 bit (Skylake AVX512, but I should target also Icelake-client and Alderlake, and possibly a few others)
- Python 3.9.11 64 bit
- Cython 0.29.32, NumPy 1.21.5
- GCC 11.2.0 (I could go to GCC 12 if needed)

I compile the Cython script posted below with these flags:

```
-O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -ftree-vectorize
```

### Problem Description

I cannot change the way these matrices are generated nor their dtype, and I have to repeatedly find the nonzero elements in these matrices, and in particular these 4 information:

1. The number of nonzero elements
2. A 1D array of row indices at which elements of the matrix are nonzero
3. A 1D  array of column indices at which elements of the matrix are nonzero
4. A 1D array containing the nonzero elements

Of course, len(row_indices) = len(column_indices) = len(x) = number of nonzeros

In the scripts below I have implemented 3 approaches:

1. "Naive": Loop through all the 2D array elements (first by columns, then by row) and see if the element is nonzero. If it is, store its `i` and `j` indices and the array value in 3 separated, previously `malloc`ed arrays
2. "Memcmp": For each column, compare 64 floats at the time against a zero-array using `memcmp`. If `memcmp` returns a non-zero value, there is at least one nonzero element between row `k` and row `k + 64`
3. "Blocks": Similar to the "Memcmp" approach, but it uses the clever technique in the first answer of this post: ([Fastest way to check mass data if null in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450237/fastest-way-to-check-mass-data-if-null-in-c)) and later modifications by @Peter Cordes.

I need these 3 arrays (`row_indices` for `i` indices, `col_starts` for `j` indices and `x` for nonzero floats in the matrix) to pass them to another library.

### C/Cython/Python Scripts

*nnz_c_support.h* (C code, used by the Cython script)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>

__attribute__ ((hot)) int dataisnull(const void *data, size_t length) {
    /* assuming data was returned by malloc, thus is properly aligned */
    size_t i = 0, i0, n = length / sizeof(size_t);
    const size_t *pw = data;
    const unsigned char *pb = data;
#define UNROLL_FACTOR  8
#if UNROLL_FACTOR == 8
    size_t n1 = n - n % UNROLL_FACTOR;
    for (; i < n1; i += UNROLL_FACTOR) {
        size_t val = pw[i + 0] | pw[i + 1] | pw[i + 2] | pw[i + 3] |
                     pw[i + 4] | pw[i + 5] | pw[i + 6] | pw[i + 7];
        if (val)
            return i+1;
    }
#endif
    size_t val = 0;

    // gcc and clang think they should autovectorize this cleanup loop
    // using a single-byte accumulator convinces them at least not to unpack bytes to size_t before ORing
    i0 = i+1;
    i *= sizeof(size_t);
    // i = n * sizeof(size_t)
    unsigned char bval = 0;
    for (; i < length; i++) {
        bval |= pb[i];
    }
    return ((val|bval) != 0 ? i0 : 0);
}
```

*nonzero.pyx* (Cython code with the 3 different methods)

```
#cython: language_level=3,boundscheck=False,wraparound=False,nonecheck=False,initializedcheck=False,cdivision=True
###############################################################################

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, calloc, free
from libc.string cimport memcmp

cdef int MAXNNZ = 500000

DTYPE_float = np.float32
ctypedef np.float32_t DTYPE_float_t

cdef extern from "nnz_c_support.h" nogil:   
    cdef int dataisnull(const void *data, size_t length)
            


cdef int find_nnz_naive(DTYPE_float_t[::1, :] matrix) nogil:

    cdef int n, m, i, j, k, nza, nelem, next_k
    cdef float val1
        
    m = matrix.shape[0]
    n = matrix.shape[1]

    nelem = min(m*n, MAXNNZ)

    col_starts  = <int*> malloc(sizeof(int)*nelem)
    row_indices = <int*> malloc(sizeof(int)*nelem)
    x           = <double*> malloc(sizeof(double)*nelem)

    nza = 0
            
    for i in range(n):

        for j in range(m):
            val1 = matrix[j, i]
                
            if val1 != 0.0:
                nza = nza + 1
                # Store i, j and val1 indices/values in 3 arrays
                # x has to be an array of doubles
                col_starts[nza] = i + 1
                row_indices[nza] = j + 1
                x[nza] = val1

    free(x)
    free(row_indices)
    free(col_starts)
                                    
    return nza
    


cdef int find_nnz_memcmp(DTYPE_float_t[::1, :] matrix) nogil:

    cdef int n, m, i, j, k, nza, nelem, next_k
    cdef int mcpi
    cdef float val1

    m = matrix.shape[0]
    n = matrix.shape[1]
    
    cdef int bytes_per_float = 4
        
    cdef int n_floats_per_block = 64 if m > 512 else 32
    cdef int comp_bytes = n_floats_per_block * bytes_per_float
    
    test_block = <float*> calloc(n_floats_per_block, sizeof(float))

    nelem = min(m*n, MAXNNZ)

    col_starts  = <int*> malloc(sizeof(int)*nelem)
    row_indices = <int*> malloc(sizeof(int)*nelem)
    x           = <double*> malloc(sizeof(double)*nelem)

    nza = 0
            
    for i in range(n):

        k = 0
        
        while k < m:
            
            mcpi = memcmp(&test_block[0], &matrix[k, i], comp_bytes)
            next_k = min(m, k + n_floats_per_block)

            if mcpi == 0:
                k = next_k
                continue
                                                    
            for j in range(k, next_k):
                val1 = matrix[j, i]
                
                if val1 != 0.0:
                    nza = nza + 1
                    # Store i, j and val1 indices/values in 3 arrays
                    # x has to be an array of doubles
                    col_starts[nza] = i + 1
                    row_indices[nza] = j + 1
                    x[nza] = val1

                    
            k = next_k
                
    free(x)
    free(row_indices)
    free(col_starts)
    free(test_block)
    return nza


cdef int find_nnz_blocks(DTYPE_float_t[::1, :] matrix) nogil:

    cdef int n, m, i, j, k, nza, nelem, next_k
    cdef int mcpi, reminder, comp_bytes
    cdef float val1

    m = matrix.shape[0]
    n = matrix.shape[1]
                
    nelem = min(m*n, MAXNNZ)

    col_starts  = <int*> malloc(sizeof(int)*nelem)
    row_indices = <int*> malloc(sizeof(int)*nelem)
    x           = <double*> malloc(sizeof(double)*nelem)

    cdef int bytes_per_float = 4
        
    cdef int n_floats_per_block = 64 if m > 512 else 32
    cdef int comp_bytes_default = n_floats_per_block * bytes_per_float

    reminder = 4*(m % n_floats_per_block)
    nza = 0
                        
    for i in range(n):

        k = 0
        
        while k < m:
            
            comp_bytes = comp_bytes_default
            next_k = k + n_floats_per_block
            if next_k >= m:
                comp_bytes = reminder
                next_k = m

            mcpi = dataisnull(&matrix[k, i], comp_bytes) 

            if mcpi != 0:
                for j in range(k + mcpi - 1, next_k):
                    val1 = matrix[j, i]
                    
                    if val1 != 0.0:
                        nza = nza + 1
                        # Store i, j and val1 indices/values in 3 arrays
                        # x has to be an array of doubles
                        col_starts[nza] = i + 1
                        row_indices[nza] = j + 1
                        x[nza] = val1
                    
            k = next_k

    free(x)
    free(row_indices)
    free(col_starts)
                
    return nza


    
cpdef int find_nnz(DTYPE_float_t[::1, :] matrix, int method):

    with nogil:
        if method == 0:
            return find_nnz_naive(matrix)
        elif method == 1:
            return find_nnz_memcmp(matrix)
        elif method == 2:
            return find_nnz_blocks(matrix)
```

*setup.py* (Python file to compile the Cython one into pyd)

```
import os

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import Extension

from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import numpy as np

# ==================================================================================================================== #
# C extensions
# ==================================================================================================================== #
EXTRA_COMPILE_ARGS = ['-O3', '-ffast-math', '-funroll-loops', '-flto', '-ftree-vectorize', '-DMS_WIN64']
EXTRA_LINK_ARGS = ['-flto', '-static'] + EXTRA_COMPILE_ARGS



class CustomBuildExt(build_ext):
    def build_extensions(self):
        # Override the compiler executables. Importantly, this
        # removes the "default" compiler flags that would
        # otherwise get passed on to to the compiler, i.e.,
        # distutils.sysconfig.get_var("CFLAGS").
        self.compiler.set_executable("compiler_so", "gcc -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64")
        self.compiler.set_executable("compiler_cxx", "g++ -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64")
        self.compiler.set_executable("linker_so", "gcc -shared -static")
        self.compiler.dll_libraries = []
        build_ext.build_extensions(self)

def Compile():

    extension_kwargs = {'extra_compile_args': EXTRA_COMPILE_ARGS,
                        'extra_link_args'   : EXTRA_LINK_ARGS,
                        'include_dirs'      : [np.get_include()],
                        'define_macros'     : [('WIN32', 1)]}

    module_name = 'nonzero'
    extension = Extension(module_name, [module_name + '.pyx'], **extension_kwargs)

    # build the core extension(s)
    setup_kwargs = {'cmdclass': {'build_ext': CustomBuildExt},
                    'ext_modules': cythonize(extension,
                                             compiler_directives={'embedsignature'  : False,
                                                                  'boundscheck'     : False,
                                                                  'wraparound'      : False,
                                                                  'initializedcheck': False,
                                                                  'cdivision'       : True,
                                                                  'nonecheck'       : False,
                                                                  'language_level'  : '3str'},
                                             force=True,
                                             cache=False,
                                             quiet=False)}

    setup(**setup_kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Compile()
```

*main.py* (Python test file, to run timings and tests)

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

from nonzero import find_nnz


def create_matrix(m, n, density):
    """
    Creates a `m` x `n` single-precision, fortran-ordered dense matrix
    with a density of nonzero elements specified by `density` (as percentage)
    """

    n_elem = m * n

    # Number of non zero values
    size = int(round(density / 100.0 * n_elem))

    raveled_ind = np.random.choice(n_elem, size=size, replace=False)
    i_ind, j_ind = np.unravel_index(raveled_ind, shape=(m, n))

    matrix = np.zeros((m, n), dtype=np.float32, order='F')
    matrix[i_ind, j_ind] = 1e3 * np.random.randn(size)

    return matrix


N_TRIALS = 1000

NAIVE  = 0
MEMCMP = 1
BLOCKS = 2

METHODS_STRINGS = ['Naive', 'Memcmp', 'Blocks']
METHODS_ID = [NAIVE, MEMCMP, BLOCKS]


def time_nonzero(m, n, density):

    matrix = create_matrix(m, n, density)

    assert matrix.dtype == np.float32, 'Single precision floats only'
    assert np.isfortran(matrix), 'Matrix is not Fortran ordered'

    nnz = np.count_nonzero(matrix)

    print('%-6d  %-6d  %-6d  %-8.4f' % (m, n, nnz, density), end=' ')
    nnz_naive = find_nnz(matrix, NAIVE)
    nnz_memcmp = find_nnz(matrix, MEMCMP)
    nnz_blocks = find_nnz(matrix, BLOCKS)

    assert nnz_naive == nnz_memcmp, 'NNZ (naive) = %d, NNZ (memcmp) = %d' % (nnz_naive, nnz_memcmp)
    assert nnz_naive == nnz_blocks, 'NNZ (naive) = %d, NNZ (blocks) = %d' % (nnz_naive, nnz_blocks)

    glb = {'constraint_matrix': matrix}

    for method_id, method_name in zip(METHODS_ID, METHODS_STRINGS):
        elapsed = timeit.timeit("find_nnz(constraint_matrix, %d)" % method_id,
                                globals=glb,
                                setup="from __main__ import find_nnz", number=N_TRIALS)
        elapsed = elapsed * 1e3 / N_TRIALS
        print('%-7.3f' % elapsed, end=' ')

    print()

# ------------------------------------------- #
# Test cases with various m, n and densities

#              M     N     Density (%)
TEST_CASES = [[1694, 2684, 0.1262],
              [6295, 6955, 0.0281],
              [4126, 5335, 0.0386],
              [625 , 860 , 0.2366],
              [491 , 667 , 0.2931],
              [478 , 680 , 0.3295],
              [780 , 1545, 0.2254],
              [1012, 756 , 0.2189],
              [1333, 1724, 0.1312],
              [1699, 4021, 0.0883],
              [3248, 3677, 0.0598],
              [195 , 588 , 1.2245],
              [1915, 3013, 0.0935],
              [546 , 1475, 0.2297]]

# ------------------------------------------- #


def main():

    methods_names = ''.join(['%-8s' % name for name in METHODS_STRINGS])
    print('M       N       NNZ     Density  ' + methods_names)
    for m, n, density in TEST_CASES:
        time_nonzero(m, n, density)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Command to compile the Cython file:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32 --verbose --force
```

### Results

Running the benchmarks above (it takes about 2 minutes on my machine), I get this (times are in milliseconds, Skylake AVX512):

[image]

As you can see, the "Memcmp" approach is about 20% faster than the "Naive" one, while the "Blocks" approach is more than 30% faster than "Naive" (at least for larger matrices).

For some obscure (to me) reasons, if I **remove/comment out** these 3 lines in all 3 methods:

```
col_starts[nza] = i + 1
row_indices[nza] = j + 1
x[nza] = val1
```

But leave in the `nza = nza + 1`, then the "Naive" approach is the fastest by a wide margin (30% or more) (!!!!).

In any case, any suggestion you may have to make my not-so-nice code run faster is most welcome.

Comment: If you have AVX512, you can use [`vcompressps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcompressps) to compress a vector of values.

Comment: @chtz, as I wrote at the beginning of the post, I have AVX512 but I have to provide for other CPUs as well - which may not support AVX512 instructions (Icelake-client, Alderlake, possibly others).

Comment: @chtz: Even with AVX-512 available, for very sparse matrices it may be faster to do a branchy scan for non-zero values, without `dst += _popcount_u32(mask)` and a 2x p5 uop compress.  But yeah when you find a non-zero vector, `vcompressps` is probably your best bet instead of `_tzcnt_u32(mask)` and looping over its set bits which might not predict well if non-zero floats ever come in clumps.

Comment: Another possible strategy is creating a temporary bitmap of 1024 or 4096 elements (so the floats are still hot in L1d) with AVX-512 or with `_mm256_cmpne_ps` / `_mm256_movemask_ps`, then you loop over that bitmap in 64 or 128-bit chunks.  Or in even larger chunks with SIMD for this, like in [Efficiently find least significant set bit in a large array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67779725) .

Comment: Perhaps arrange the branching such hat zero or one set bit per 64-bit chunk branches the same way, copying a float from `src[i+32]` like `*dst = src[i + tzcnt(mask)]` but *not* advancing the destination pointer if the bitmap was actually zero, like `dst += (mask != 0)`.  (Or pointers plural, for row and column index arrays, too.)  This is probably best for a density of 1 to 2%, but branchy maybe better for a very low density.  We can count average density over a chunk of 4096 bits as we generate it, with `counts = _mm256_sub_epi32(counts, castps_si256(cmpps))`

Comment: Without AVX512 (but AVX2) you could also try (after `_mm256_cmpne_ps`/`_mm256_movemask_ps`) to do a `if(!mask) continue; else switch(mask){ case 1: /* extract lowest element, increment output ptr by 1*/ break; case 2: ...}` (maybe split the mask in two halves with only 16 cases each)

Comment: ... or have a 256 element LUT of 8byte entries with indexes, which are expanded to 32bit as input for a `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` (the last entry can also encode by how much the pointer needs to be incremented)

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes and chtz. Unfortunately, your knowledge is wasted on me, I simply do not possess the skills to convert what you suggested into working code. But I appreciate it and I’m grateful for the suggestions.

Comment: I mostly commented with ideas for others to build on if they want to write an answer or reply with any refinements.  Or for future readers.  If I get around to it, I might write some code to see how these ideas work in practice.

Comment: @chtz: https://godbolt.org/z/Wq41vGaeT is a work-in-progress of some pure C code I was playing around with.  Working in chunks of 1024 floats: make a bitmap of non-zero elements (4 cycles per 32 bits or floats, bottleneck on port 5 on Intel, pack/shuffle and vpmovmskb).  Then tzcnt / blsr in 64-bit chunks to make a list of offsets, in a do{}while that branches the same way for u64 chunks with 0 or 1 set bit, uiCA predicts 3.5 or 3 cycles per u64 assuming none have multiple set bits. Then gather floats (SIMD or scalar because of Downfall), and calculate row/col indexes from offset-within-chunk.

Comment: @PeterCordes (also for reference): These are the solutions I had in mind with permutation-LUTs of -jump-tables: https://godbolt.org/z/44hs4Ed8x. This is only the inner building block, i.e., the part which would extract the non-zeroes from a `__m128` register. Not sure if expanding the LUT to 256 entries would be worth the effort, but probably the first `cmpps`/`movmskps` could be done on 8 elements for a larger (but rarer) zero-case.

Comment: Actual throughputs of any method would depend a lot on the density pattern. I would assume with density way below 1% your `tzcnt` approach will be faster. Although, with `cmpps`/`movmskps`/`test`/`jz` my idea would need just 3 (or 4?) cycles for 4 elements in ~96% of all cases (or ~92% when checking 8 elements).

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes for providing your work-in-progress. I have optimistically taken it as it is and splattered it in my code, but running it makes the Python kernel die. I am trying to see where the problem may be, the only thing I can say for now is that it bombs somewhere in the last do/while loop - at least this is what I deduce from my initial cumbersome attempts to debug it.

Comment: The last loop is very unfinished, and I just noticed it has a stray `j+=4` that was already done by `j++` inside the unrolled iteration, so it's probably reading garbage and using it as an array index.  It probably has other bugs in terms of updating `row` for the start of the next chunk.  I didn't test this at all since I've never used Cython and didn't take the time to get that test harness set up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some (still barely tested) pure C code which converts a column major dense matrix into row/col-idx and nonzero values.

This is an improved version, based on suggestions by @PeterCordes, mostly to use 256bit vectors especially for the early out branching.

And compression of non-zeros uses `pext`/`pdep` now, inspired by this question: *[AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240)* -- I use `vpmovmskb` to save a multiplication.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

size_t extractNonZeros(float *out, uint32_t * rowidx, __m256 x, uint32_t mask, uint32_t start_row)
{
    // mask has 4 bits set for each valid element of x
    // compress corresponding index-nibbles:
    uint64_t indexes =  _pext_u64(0x76543210, mask);
    // expand nibbles to bytes:
    indexes = _pdep_u64(indexes, 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f);
    // expand bytes to 32bits:
    __m256i perm = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_cvtsi64_si128(indexes));
    // extract corresponding values from x vector
    x = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(x, perm);
    // store 8 elements -- usually also writes some garbage, which will be overwritten by the next extraction
    _mm256_storeu_ps(out, x); 

    // add the current startindex to perm to get the inner indexes
    perm = _mm256_add_epi32(perm, _mm256_set1_epi32(start_row));
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i_u*) rowidx, perm);

    return _mm_popcnt_u32(mask)/4;
}

size_t dense_to_sparse(float* nonzeros, uint32_t *colidx, uint32_t *rowidx, const float *matrix, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    if(rows == 0) return 0;
    float *out = nonzeros;
    const size_t first_rows = ((rows + 7) & 7) +1;
    const uint32_t first_rows_mask = (1ULL << (4*first_rows)) - 1;

    for(size_t c=0; c<cols; ++c) { 
        const float *colstart = matrix + rows*c;
        float *out_start = out; // to count nnz of current column
        {
            __m256 x = _mm256_loadu_ps(colstart);
            uint32_t mask = first_rows_mask & _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_cmp_ps(_mm256_setzero_ps(), x, _CMP_NEQ_UQ)));
            if(mask != 0)
            {
                size_t NNZ = extractNonZeros(out, rowidx, x, mask, 0);
                out += NNZ;
                rowidx += NNZ;
            }
        }
        for(size_t r=first_rows; r<rows; r+=8) {
            __m256 x = _mm256_loadu_ps(colstart + r);
            uint32_t mask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_cmp_ps(_mm256_setzero_ps(), x, _CMP_NEQ_UQ)));
            if(mask == 0) continue; 
            size_t NNZ = extractNonZeros(out, rowidx, x, mask, r);
            out += NNZ;
            rowidx += NNZ;
        }


        // You can manually vectorize this to write blocks of 8 values
        for(int r=0; r<(out - out_start); ++r)
        {
            *colidx++ = c;
        }
    }
    return out - nonzeros; // total number of non-zeros
}
```

The code also handles odd row-sizes now. With some more effort, the last rows of the current column could be combined with the first of the next column. Maybe this is worth optimizing if your input has only a few rows.

The method which calls this method needs to make sure that
`nonzeros`, `colidx`, and `rowidx` can store NNZ+7 elements (there will be up to 7 invalid outputs after the end) -- however `rows * cols` elements will always be sufficient (assuming `rows % 8 == 0`).

godbolt-link with simple testcase: https://godbolt.org/z/Po7YjjEqW

Old version working on 128bit vectors with a LUT-based compress for reference: https://godbolt.org/z/xW7EvEhzs

Comment: Thank you very much for this @chtz. I have run my benchmarks above with your code as well, making sure that the number of rows was a multiple of 4. I have also added a larger matrix (just for fun) at 10,132 x 11,540 in size.


What can be noticed (results here: https://imgur.com/a/0ux90uO) is that for smaller matrices your method is, on average, about 20% faster. For larger matrices, however, it becomes slower than the "Blocks" approach. I haven't found the breakeven point but it looks like it's around 5,000 x 5,000 more or less.

Comment: The OP's non-zero density is typically 1% or less, at most 2%.  Probably better to at least do the early-out branch on 8 floats at once, since the OP says we can assume at least x86-64-v3 (Alder Lake).  Doing the actual left-pack on 8 floats at once *might* be worth it *[AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240)* if we don't care about Zen 2 and earlier AMD (slow `pdep`), or you could split up the movemask result into separate 4-bit nibbles for the low half (`cast`) and high half (`_mm256_extractf128_ps`).

Comment: Interesting overload of the LUT for an increment, although you can do that cheaply with `_popcnt_u32`, which might be about the same cost as `movzx`-load + 3-component `lea` like `lea rdi, [rdi + rcx*4 + 4]` to increment a pointer.  vs. with popcount we don't need the extra `+1` so it can be a 2-component LEA which is better for Skylake, lower latency for the pointer dep chains (but fortunately with the early out being taken most of the time, pointer-update latency shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: The `*colidx++ = c;` can be vectorized with overshoot allowed, assuming the caller significantly over-allocates without knowing density and will realloc to shrink later.  So `_mm256_set1_epi32(c)` and do `_mm256_storeu_si256` until `colidx+=8` is >=  `initial_colidx + (out-out_start)`.

Comment: I agree on early-out branching with 8 floats. I did not bother to implement/benchmark that. Regarding `*colidx++ = c;`, I assumed that this gets auto-vectorized well-enough by the compiler and also did not bother to micro-optimize this ("Usually" I wouldn't even store this but only mark the beginning and end of the current column in `rowidx`).

Comment: Here is a version working on 256bit vectors, using `pext`/`pdep` to create the shuffle mask as suggested by @PeterCordes: https://godbolt.org/z/Po7YjjEqW (also handling arbitrary number of rows (only sparsely tested ...). I'll later edit this answer with the new version.

Comment: @Infinity77 I assume the main impact in your benchmark was the density of the matrices. Can you check my improved version? It should be almost twice as fast on very sparse matrices. With AVX512 it could again be (almost) improved by a factor of two.

Comment: @chtz Thank you for all this work, it's very enlightening. I have run your code on 2 different machines (a Xeon workstation and at 13th gen Intel laptop). Your code is about 5-10% faster than the "Blocks" approach for large matrices and about 30-40% faster for smaller matrices. Timings here: https://imgur.com/a/49HV6Pd .